# How to remove the time in Date() Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, date, time

Hi I have a code like this.

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();

var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
```

The result is like this:

```
"Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
```

How do I remove the time and other texts so that I'll have a result like this:

```
"Thu Sep 01"
```

I already tried `.split(' ')[0]` and `.replace` but it says that it is not a function.

Thanks!

Comment: How about this:
`firstDay.toDateString();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the date object to a string, then do your manipulation.

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();

var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1).toString().split(' ').slice(0,3).join(' ');

console.log(firstDay)
```